# ASP.NET Default page redirect when entering role restricted webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am using VS2005 ASP.NET 2.0.

I am using web.config file to for my role management for specific role privileged webpages with the following code in my global (not in the Administrator folder) web.config file:

```
<location path="Administrator">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny roles="User"/>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The webpage can be role restricted, thus disallowing users without the role of *Administrator* to access.

However, when users of any role tries to enter the restricted webpage, they will be automatically redirected to the login page with URL like

`http://localhost:2232/App/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSoD%2fAdministrator%2fUserMgmt.aspx`

This will require the user to press the button back to go back to the previous page.

This is causing me trouble in terms of error handling as this shouldn't be happening, instead, an error page should be shown.

May I know if there is any solution or parameters which I can declare for the default redirection for each folder/page?

---

P.S.

I have a custom error tag which declare error pages with each error code attached.

Is there an error code which I can use when a user enters a role-restricted website?

E.g.

```
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/UnexpectedError.aspx" mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
```

---

Solution for redirecting **LOGGED IN** User to error page:

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))

            Response.Redirect("/App/Error/UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

How can I redirect a user to an error page if he/she is not logged in and tries to enter a role-restricted webpage?

Comment: Why would that URL *require the user to press the button back to go back to the previous page*? It looks right to me. Login.aspx is the login page, and the ReturnUrl query argument is the URL to redirect to after the user successfully logs in.

Comment: @JonathanWood if the user enters a role restricted webpage without having the require role privilege, he/she should be redirected to an error page instead of the login page.

Comment: Then I can't follow because, above, you said when an unauthorized user accesses the page that they'll be redirected to the login page, and then you gave a URL that looks like a login page to me.

Comment: @JonathanWood The solution has been solved, but what I meant is that I would want to redirect unauthorized user to an error page which says "Unauthorized user" instead if the login page URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use else condition i am make this change

```
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
       {
          Response.Redirect("Acces page");
        }
       else
       {

        Response.Redirect("/App/Error/UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a web.config setting that determines the URL unauthorized users are redirected to.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This is intended to be a login page, but it could just as easily be a page with any sort of message.

Comment: Yes I have this settings set in my webconfig as well. I would like to redirect authorized user to an error page if they access an unauthorized page (page that requires a higher privilege), and I found the solution which is to use the post back method in my login page.

Comment: Up to you. But why not just change the setting above to refer to the URL where your error page is?